# R: Plot not doing anything at all

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a lot of stored stock data which are read from CSV files. Basically the BasketName defines a Textfile in which all required stock titles are saved (stock titles are referred to as variables in my program).

```
#Goes through all variables in a basket and saves the resulting plots to the specified directory as jpeg files
plotBasketAndSaveToDirectory<-function(BasketName, SaveToDirectory){
    BasketVariables <- readVariablesFromBasket(BasketName)

    for(i in 1:nrow(BasketVariables)){
      VariableCSV<-read.table(getVariableCSVPath(BasketVariables[i,1]),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep=",")
      VariableCSV$Date<-as.Date(as.character(VariableCSV$Date), format="%Y/%m/%d")
      VariableXTS<-xts(VariableCSV$Close, order.by=VariableCSV$Date)
      #jpeg(filename=paste(SaveToDirectory,BasketVariables[1,1],".jpeg",sep=""))
      plot(VariableXTS)
      #dev.off
    }
}
```

My function getVariableCSVPath returns the correct path for a stock title in this Basket.

The CSV files are constructed with the following headers:

```
Date High Low Open Close Volume
```

Now I want to read the csv file for each stock (variable) in this basket individually with read.table and create a plot and save it to the disc. However if I comment the whole saving part and want to see the plot to check if it works, nothing happens...But my xts variable is correctly displayed, all Dates are set. Maybe some Dates are missing in between due to weekends and holidays but this shouldn't be a problem right? But the program doesn't show any error it just doesn't plot anything. I've tried to run it with ChartSeries() from another package and there it shows this error:

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is `readVariablesFromBasket` ? You never define it.  Your descriptions of what you've done are from clear. Please show a small reproducible dataset so we can verify that ,e.g., `VariableXTS` even gets created and what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

If VariableXTS is an xts object, I don't believe you're calling plot on it correctly.

Check page 11 of the reference manual for the xts package, as it has a half page on plotting of xts objects:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/vignettes/xts.pdf

It appears you have to explicitly define axes